# Исключения The process cannot access the file "FilePath" because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, файлы

есть такая проблема

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.File.Move("resours/image/printscreen.txt", "resours/image/printscreen.jpg");
            this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");
            File.Delete("resours/image/printscreen.jpg"); // думал ошибка исчезнет 
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("resours/image/printscreen.jpg"); // вот тут появляется исключения 
            System.IO.File.Move("resours/image/printscreen.txt", "resours/image/printscreen.jpg");
            this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");
        }
```

мне надо както виходить из файла после переобразования , есть `using` но как его использвоть при `system.io.file.delete` ?

сперва работает функция `button1_Click();` после `button2_Click();`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в:

1. `this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");`
   вы говорите  picturebox1 где брать фото , он берет использует эти данные
   2.`File.Delete("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");`а потом вы хотите удалить

чтобы удалить должно быть так :
`this.pictureBox1.Image = null;` // перестать использовать 
`File.Delete("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");` //удалить

если все же надо отображать фото то пишите его в память а после удаляйте фото
вот ссылка : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088443/view-image-file-without-locking-it-copy-to-memory

Comment: мне надо решить проблему а имено както вийти из файла чтоб делать другие действия с ними , это просто пример .