# Работа с файлом изображения

Tags: c#, windows, изображения

у меня при работе с картинками появилась проблема при

`this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("resours/image/printscreen.jpg");`

после я не могу ничего делать с файлом `printscreen.jpg` и я получаю исключения 
`The process cannot access the file "FilePath" because it is being used by another process` , как мне залить картинку и после работать с файлом далее?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Исключения The process cannot access the file "FilePath" because it is being used by another process](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096158/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-filepath-because-it-is-being-use)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там есть пояснение причины проблемы, но нет нормального ршения проблемы.

Comment: @tym32167 Ну так пусть кто либо другой даст более развернутый ответ там, вопрос ведь один и тот же. А если автору надо добавить информацию в сам вопрос, то всегда можно подправить то, что есть. Какой смысл сейчас в этом вопросе, если есть тот?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну или пусть даст ответ тут, а тот отметим дубликатом :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну формально там есть ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Вот после таких решений все SO и кишит дубликатами. Извините, но мне вас не понять))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример открываем и показываем файл, а потом его можно удалить.

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //путь к открытому файлу
    private string _activePictureFile;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _buttonOpen.Click += ButtonOpen_Click;
        _buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        //запоминаем путь к файлу
        _activePictureFile = _openFileDialog.FileName;
        //открываем файл через его копию в памяти
        var memStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(_activePictureFile));
        _pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(memStream);
    }

    private void ButtonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить файл?", "Вопрос", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
            return;

        //удаляем файл
        File.Delete(_activePictureFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Документация о Image.FromFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.8) говорит черным по белому, что файл изображения будет заблокирован пока Image не будет удален.

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

Вывод - не используйте его, если надо и дальше работать с файлом.

Используйте альтернативные методы, к примеру создать поток и уже из потока прочитать изображение [Image.FromStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.8).

```
byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes("path/sample.jpg");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(contents);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```